# Python version doesn't update from 3.9.0 to 3.11.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

I installed python 3.11.2, so now I have two python versions installed(python 3.9.0 was installed previously), but I can't switch to the latest one.

[Command line (--version)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y3aeE.png)

[Interpreters in VSCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHZp6.png)

Comment: Try with `py -3.11`

Comment: Can you explain the issue, what you've tried, what errors you got. Also just a heads up posting text as an image is not really appreciated here.

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM this method worked as well! Thanks

Comment: @ShadowCrafter_01 Fixed my issue, but thanks for the heads up regarding text as an image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you use them. You can't run both versions straight ahead through a terminal window outside of their respective paths, because they are processed in the manner stablished by the PATH environment variable.

You have some options:

- Using BAT/CMD scripts: Run both of them with full path.
- Using a PS / terminal window: Run both of them within their respective paths.
- Using a PS / terminal window: Run one of them within their path and the other one from anywhere. For this to work you have to reorder the PATH environment variable so this last one appears first and works like a Windows command.
- Uninstalling the version you don't need: Then you can run the other one however you want.

If you don't know to how edit the PATH environment variable check [this HowToGeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/787217/how-to-edit-environment-variables-on-windows-10-or-11/) article

Comment: Changed the path and everything seems to be working as expected! Thanks!